# "go get package" fails with "git-pull is broken"

Tags: git, go, centos

I am having trouble with git and golang. I just installed go version `go1.8 linux/amd64` now and when I execute any `go get package` commands, I receive this message:

```
git pull --ff-only
fatal: 'pull' appears to be a git command, but we were not
able to execute it. Maybe git-pull is broken?
```

So, I reinstalled git twice by doing:

- `yum reinstall git`
- `yum remove git, yum clean all, yum install git`

But, I am still getting the same error message.

What else can be giving me problems?

The current version of git is `git version 1.8.3.1` and my OS is CentOS7.

Comment: Is it possible that it is trying to execute that command from a directory that is not a git repository?

Comment: If you try from the command line, does it work?

Comment: @litelite I am making that from the command line

Comment: @0x5453 the thing is that I dont execute git directly, "Go get" do that automatically

Comment: If you can't execute git directly, this isn't really a programming question. Do you have any `GIT_*` environment variables set incorrectly? Have you tried a new login shell after reinstalling git?

Comment: @JimB I tested cloning a repo and it worked correctly

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova: you said you ran `git pull --ff-only` from the command line and got that same error. Regardless, this is a git error, so I would be looking at things related to that installation, like the relevant env variables, git config for the repo in question, etc.

Comment: @JimB The OP clearly stated he is using `get get [PACKAGE]` and receiving the error message that includes `git pull --ff-only`, and he also cloned a repo with git directly and was successful.

Comment: @Gavin: the second and third comment suggest otherwise.

Comment: also in git submodule command gives me error